# React Native - Native UI Components

Tags: react-native

I got a native view which requires three properties set before I run a function. How do I achieve it in iOS? In Android we can override the function "onAfterUpdateTransaction" in ViewManager. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate and show some code?

Answer (score 3):

After trace through the code, I found that we can extend RCTView and override the function 'didSetProps'. This function will be called after all properties are set.

Example code:

In your .h file

```
@interface AdView : RCTView
```

.m file

```
- (void)didSetProps:(NSArray<NSString *> *)changedProps {
  [self loadAd]; //Do your stuff here
}
```